# Help with Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

Below is the trigger code but i am getting error:

> Compile Error: unexpected token: 'List' at line 12 column 2

```
trigger onUpdateOfObjectB on Object_B__c(Before insert,before update) {

set<String> Idval=new set<String>();
set<Integer> Ids=new set<Integer>();

  for (Object_B__c ct: trigger.new)
 {
    idval.add(ct.Lookup_Object_A__c);
    ids.add(ct.Id);
 }

  List Aclist=[select Id,Priority__c from Object_A__c where Id =:Idval];

  List Bclist=new List();
  List Cclist=[select Lookup_Object_B__c,Status__c from Object_C__c where Lookup_Object_B__c=:ids];

    for(Object_A__c ac: Aclist)
    {
      for(Object_C__c cc: Cclist)
      {
       if(ac.Priority__c=='P1' && cc.Status__c=='Closed')
         {
           System.debug('SDFGsdf sdfsdf');
           cc.addError('Your custom error message');
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Please help me to resolve t

Comment: It would greatly help if you specify the error you are getting.

Comment: Compile Error: unexpected token: 'List' at line 12 column 2

Comment: Ah, I overlooked that one, have added it to my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

When performing SOQL and you want to filter on a list of values in the where clause, use the `IN` keyword. Additionally, use the ID type when you're working with IDs.

Lists and other collections are hard typed and need to be initialized for a specific type. Have a look at [the documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_collections_lists.htm)

```
set<ID> Idval=new set<ID>();//collection
set<ID> Ids=new set<ID>();

  for (Object_B__c ct: trigger.new)
 {
    idval.add(ct.Lookup_Object_A__c);
    ids.add(ct.Id);
 }

  List<Object_A__c> Aclist=[select Id,Priority__c from Object_A__c where Id IN :Idval];

  //List<??> Bclist=new List()<??>; //List<TYPE>(); 
  List<Object_C__c> Cclist=[select Lookup_Object_B__c,Status__c from Object_C__c where Lookup_Object_B__c IN :ids];
```

It believe this should solve your error.